# disable server manager on Windows Server 2016 with chef recipe

Tags: windows, powershell, chef-infra

Is there any way to disable launching/killing Server Manager on Windows Server 2016 at the user log-on using some PowerShell command or chef recipe?

Server Manager on Windows Server 2016 launches on every user log-on and it is really annoying as we hardly use it for any reason

IT Infra cannot disable it at organization level so we want to disable it on some specific servers only.

Comment: https://www.tachytelic.net/2018/11/disable-server-manager-from-starting-when-logging-in-to-windows-server-2016/

Comment: `Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName ServerManager | Disable-ScheduledTask -Verbose` works too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do have a Chef recipe that sets the appropriate registry key to disable Server Manager from launching on login. The resource definition should be:

```
registry_key 'Disable Server Manager on Login' do
  values [{
      name: 'DoNotOpenServerManagerAtLogon',
      type: :dword,
      data: 0x1,
  }]
  key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\ServerManager'
  action :create
  recursive true
end
```

Comment: Nice, on which server you tried that? I am planning to use it on Windows2016

Comment: Works on 2012R2, and 2016. I haven't verified that it works on 2019 yet but the folks who complained to have me implement this haven't complained thus far.